# LinkedList<T> can not be serialized using the XMLSerializer

Tags: .net, serialization, .net-2.0, xml-serialization

A LinkedList [can't be serialized](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/93538/linkedlist-t-can-not-be-serialized-using-the-xmlserializer?wa=wsignin1.0) using XmlSerializer.

Now, how to however save/retrieve data from a serialized objet LinkedList. Should I implement custom serialization?

What I tried to do:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[Serializable()]
public class TestClass
{
    private int _Id;
    private string _Name;
    private int _Age;
    private LinkedList<int> _linkedList = new LinkedList<int>();

    public string Name {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }
    
    public string Age {
        get { return _Age; }
        set { _Age = value; }
    }
    
    [XmlArray()]
    public List<int> MyLinkedList {
        get { return new List<int>(_linkedList); }
        set { _linkedList = new LinkedList<int>(value); }
    }
}
```

What I've obtained(addind name, age and some items in the mylinkedlist):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestClass 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>testName</Name>
  <Age>10</Age>
  <MyLinkedList />
</TestClass>
```

So, the items in the linked list hadn't been serialized... :(

Comment: Perhaps your test code was adding elements to the collection incorrectly?  I'll update my answer with sample code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility would be the creation of a serializable collection that contains the same objects as the linked list.  E.g. (untested):

```
LinkedList<Foo> ll = PopulateLinkedList();
List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>(ll);
```

Then serialize `list` instead.  This isn't going to create a lot of overhead if `Foo` is a reference type, and you don't care about the fact that insertions/deletions are now more expensive b/c you're only using the `List<T>` to hold references to the data for serialization and deserialization purposes.  When you pull it out of the serialized stream, you can just turn it back into a `LinkedList<T>` to get all those advantages you were using a linked list for in the first place.

---

Here's a little console app I just whipped up to demonstrate.  I did it in VS2008, but I don't think I used anything surprising-- just the array initialization syntax to save some vertical space.

**Sample Code:**

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    private string name;
    private int age;
    private LinkedList<int> linkedList = new LinkedList<int>();

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }

    [XmlArray]
    public List<int> MyLinkedList
    {
        get { return new List<int>(linkedList); }
        set { linkedList = new LinkedList<int>(value); }
    }
}
```

And the main application code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass c = new MyClass();

        c.Age = 42;
        c.Name = "MyName";
        c.MyLinkedList = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 9 }; // Your property impl requires this be set all at once, not one element at a time via the property.

        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        StringWriter outStream = new StringWriter();
        s.Serialize(outStream, c);

        Console.Write(outStream.ToString());

        return;
    }
}
```

This kicks the following out to the console:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>MyName</Name>
  <Age>42</Age>
  <MyLinkedList>
    <int>1</int>
    <int>4</int>
    <int>9</int>
  </MyLinkedList>
</MyClass>
```

Comment: @Daniel A. White:  Yep.  I didn't remember off the top of my head if that was introduced in a later version of the framework or not, and I didn't feel like looking it up.  :)

Comment: I use .NET2. Updated the try.

Comment: this is, surely, cool. Now, what if I have a public `LinkedList` member? Not a `List<T>`, but a `LinkedList<T>`. However is it, a LinkedList is not a List and viceversa.

Comment: @serhio:  Pull the code that's currently in the property (that creates the `List<T>` from the `LinkedList<T>`) out into your serialization code.