# How to Xml serialize a LinkedList?

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, xml-serialization

*.NET 2*

Actually there are methods to XML serialize a `List<T>`. 
What if I have an object that has a public `LinkedList<T>` member?

Without creating a public duplicate as `List<T>` from `LinkedList<T>`. Maybe a way to control the Xml serialization like binary (OnSerializing, OnDeserializing).

**Will be impossible to XML serialize a object with a public `LinkedList<T>` member?**

EDIT:

An test example to fix with IXmlSerializable

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Foo : IXmlSerializable {        
    private int _Id;
    private string _Name;

    public string Name {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }        
    
    private int _Age;
    public string Age {
        get { return _Age; }
        set { _Age = value; }
    }
    
    private LinkedList<Bar> _linkedList = new LinkedList<Bar>();
    [XmlArray()]
    public List<Bar> MyLinkedList {
        get { return _linkedList; }
        set { _linkedList = value; }
    }
    
    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema() {
        return null;
    }
    
    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader) {
        _Name = reader.ReadString(); // ? '            
        _Age = reader.ReadString(); // ? '
        // foreach MyLinkedList 
    }
    
    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer) {
        writer.WriteString(_Name); // ? '
        writer.WriteString(_Age); // ? '
        // foreach MyLinkedList 
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [LinkedList<T> can not be serialized using the XMLSerializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237584/linkedlistt-can-not-be-serialized-using-the-xmlserializer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible with [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) without implementing [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) or creating a public duplicate as `List<T>` from `LinkedList<T>`. [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) is capable of doing this but unfortunately it is not available in .NET 2.0.

---

UPDATE:

Here's an example of implementing [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) to serialize a `LinkedList<T>`:

```
public class Foo : IXmlSerializable
{
    public LinkedList<int> List { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("List");
        foreach (var item in List)
        {
            writer.WriteElementString("Item", item.ToString());    
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo
        {
            List = new LinkedList<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3 })
        };
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(foo.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, foo);
    }
}
```

As you can see it's basically doing the serialization by hand so there's no much benefit of the `XmlSerializer` here.

Comment: interesting about IXmlSerializable... A sample of how can I serialize a LinkedList with?

Comment: Thank you, this is interesting. Now, one more precision. What if the LinkedList<T>, where T is a custom object(say it `Bar`). Bar can be also XmlSerailizable, or custom XmlSerializable, or also not Serializable at all.